# aws cognito refresh token not validating username

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-cognito

In refresh_token scenario (REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH AuthFlow), AWS Cognito API seems to be ignoring the value passed for USERNAME field. Validation seems to be limited to an email regex parsing. i.e API allowed to fetch access token for any USERNAME such as foo@bar.com with a refresh token of user@gmail.com.

**Scenario:**
Login to Cognito:

```
response = boto3_client.admin_initiate_auth(
            UserPoolId=POOL_ID,
            AuthFlow='ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': username,
                'PASSWORD': password,
            },
            ClientId=CLIENT_ID,
        )
```

**Refresh call**
Using the login response refresh token, attempt a refresh for a different user, API did not return a failure.

```
response = boto3_client.admin_initiate_auth(
            UserPoolId=POOL_ID,
            AuthFlow='REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH',
            AuthParameters={
                'USERNAME': username, #===== different user
                'REFRESH_TOKEN': refresh_token,
            },
            ClientId=CLIENT_ID,
        )
```

Is this expected in ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH flow? or a bug in Cognito API?

Comment: Definitely not expected. If this is confirmed, raise a ticket to the AWS team as this is a security issue

Answer (score 0):

In the refresh token flow, the username is not a required parameter as the refresh token can directly be associated with the given user that the token was issued in the first place. You can test this behavior by using the AWS CLI for example and passing just the refresh token.

Comment: Do you have a source which you referred to for this? Looking at http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html I see it states 'For REFRESH_TOKEN_AUTH/REFRESH_TOKEN: USERNAME (required), SECRET_HASH (required if the app client is configured with a client secret), REFRESH_TOKEN (required), DEVICE_KEY'... i.e. the USERNAME is required, which conflicts with your answer.

Comment: I mentioned that this can be tested via the CLI. I will make an internal request to have the documentation updated.

Comment: I tried it and concur; the USERNAME is not required, so it seems the documentation needs attention.